# count the number of zero group bits in a number

Tags: c

How do you count the number of zero group bits in a number? group bits 
is any consecutive zero or one bits, for example, 2 is represented 
as ....0000000000000000010 has two zero bits groups the least 
significant bit and the group starts after one. 
Also, I am in a bad need for algorithms on bits manipulation if any 
one has a reference, please share

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple fun ways to do it. The #define-s at the beginning are only for being able to express the function inputs in binary notation. The two functions that do the work are variations on a theme: the first one uses a de Bruijn sequence and a lookup table to figure out how many trailing zeros there are in the parameter, and does the rest accordingly. The second uses a Mod37 table to do the same, which is very similar in concept but involves a modulo operation instead of a multiplication and a bit shift. One of them is faster. Too lazy to figure out which one.

This is a lot more code than the obvious solution. But this can be very effective if you have primarily zeros in the input, as it only requires one loop iteration (just one branch, actually) for every 1-bit, instead of one loop iteration for every bit.

```
#define HEX__(n) 0x##n##LU

#define B8__(x)  ((x&0x0000000FLU)?  1:0)   \
                +((x&0x000000F0LU)?  2:0)   \
                +((x&0x00000F00LU)?  4:0)   \
                +((x&0x0000F000LU)?  8:0)   \
                +((x&0x000F0000LU)? 16:0)   \
                +((x&0x00F00000LU)? 32:0)   \
                +((x&0x0F000000LU)? 64:0)   \
                +((x&0xF0000000LU)?128:0)

#define B8(d) ((unsigned char)B8__(HEX__(d)))

#define B16(dmsb,dlsb) (((unsigned short)B8(dmsb)<<8) + B8(dlsb))

#define B32(dmsb,db2,db3,dlsb) (((unsigned long)B8(dmsb)<<24) \
                              + ((unsigned long)B8(db2)<<16)  \
                              + ((unsigned long)B8(db3)<<8)   \
                              + B8(dlsb))

unsigned int count_zero_groups_debruijn(unsigned int v)
{
    // number of zero-bit groups (set to 1 if high-bit is zero)
    unsigned int g = (~(v & 0x80000000)) >> 31; 

    // lookup table for deBruijn 
    static const int _DeBruijnTable[32] = 
    {
        0,  1, 28,  2, 29, 14, 24,  3, 30, 22, 20, 15, 25, 17,  4,  8, 
        31, 27, 13, 23, 21, 19, 16,  7, 26, 12, 18,  6, 11,  5, 10,  9
    };

    do {
        // get number of trailing zeros in v
        int tz = _DeBruijnTable[((v & -v) * 0x077CB531U) >> 27];
        // increment zero group count if more than 1 trailing zero
        g += (tz > 0) * 1;
        // shift out trailing zeros and the preceding 1
        v = v >> (tz+1);
    } while (v);

    return g;
}

unsigned int count_zero_groups_mod37(unsigned int v)
{
    // number of zero-bit groups (set to 1 if high-bit is zero)
    unsigned int g = (~(v & 0x80000000)) >> 31; 

    // lookup table for mod37
    static const int _Mod37Table[] = 
    {
         0,  0,  1, 26,  2, 23, 27,  0,  3, 16, 24, 30, 28, 11,  0, 13,  4,
         7, 17,  0, 25, 22, 31, 15, 29, 10, 12,  6,  0, 21, 14,  9,  5, 20,
         8, 19, 18
    };

    do {
        // get number of trailing zeros in v
        int tz = _Mod37Table[(v & -v) % 37];
        // increment zero group count if more than 1 trailing zero
        g += (tz > 0) * 1;
        // shift out trailing zeros and the preceding 1
        v = v >> (tz+1);
    } while (v);

    return g;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(10011001,10000000,00001001,00010011)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(10011001,10000000,00001001,00010000)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(00011001,10000000,00001001,00010001)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(00011001,10000000,00001001,00010000)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 0)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 1)\n", count_zero_groups_debruijn(B32(00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(10011001,10000000,00001001,00010011)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(10011001,10000000,00001001,00010000)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(00011001,10000000,00001001,00010001)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 6)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(00011001,10000000,00001001,00010000)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 0)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(11111111,11111111,11111111,11111111)));
    printf("zero groups: %d (should be 1)\n", count_zero_groups_mod37   (B32(00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000)));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To create a bitstring which isolates the start of each group of 1 bits, we can use `x & ~(x << 1)`. Example:

```c
0b0011111000111000111000111000111111000111000111010101100111001101 |       x
0b0111110001110001110001110001111110001110001110101011001110011010 |      (x << 1)
0b1000001110001110001110001110000001110001110001010100110001100101 |     ~(x << 1)
0b0000001000001000001000001000000001000001000001010100100001000101 | x & ~(x << 1)
```

Basically, we are finding all the times there is a 0 bit followed by a 1 bit (right-to-left), which means this trick produces a bitstring where the **lowest** bit of each group of 1 bits is set to 1 in the final bitstring. This also works at the right boundary, since `~(x << 1)` always has a `1` in the least significant bit. I.e. `~(x << 1) & 1` is always `1`. Therefore we also properly match a group of 1's at the beginning of the bitstring.

To find the number of groups of 0 bits, we simply invert `x` before using the above trick, giving us `~x & ~(~x << 1)`. Note that we can't simplify that to `~x & (x << 1)` because the right boundary, i.e. least significant bit, would not be properly handled as described in the previous paragraph.

Now that we reduced each bit-group of 0's to a single 1, (e.g. `0b000111000111` -> `0b001000001000`) we simply popcount it.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t count_zero_groups(uint64_t x) {
    return __builtin_popcountll(~x & ~(~x << 1));
}
```

On modern x86-64, [this gives us 4 instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/Mr8bG9hEr), each of which should execute in 1 cycle. Therefore, we can compute the number of 0 groups in a 64-bit integer in 4 cycles on modern x86-64.

```
count_zero_groups:              ; assuming parameter `x` is in `rdi`
        not     rdi             ; y = ~x
        lea     rax, [rdi + rdi]; return_val = y + y (equal to y << 1)
        andn    rax, rax, rdi   ; return_val = ~return_val & y
        popcnt  rax, rax        ; return_val = popcnt(return_val)
        ret
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are some hints for you:

- `if (x & 1) {...}` checks if the least-significant bit of `x` is set;
- `x >>= 1` shifts the value of `x` one bit to the right;
- mind the negative numbers when you do bit manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest way is to count number of transitions from one to zero in loop using the shift of a bit mask along with bitwise `and' operation. It also necessary to check the first bit and increase obtained quantity by one if it is 0.

Answer (score 2):

Andrew's solution is without doubt the simplest to design and implement, but I can't help but wonder if there is a quicker solution using bigger bit masks.

At a job interview I was asked to write some code to identify the most significant set bit. After spending a few minutes coming up with an ultra slim ultra fast binary search using shrinking bitmasks, which I kept suddenly realising could be optimised further, and further, resulting in large quantities of scribbles on lots of pieces of paper, the examiner looked at me blankly and asked if I knew how to use a `for` loop.

Maybe he should have just asked me to use a for loop to solve the problem.

Anyway it's not impossible that a similar such solution exists here.

Comment: Maybe he should have asked you, in the absence of performance requirements, to write the simplest thing that works ;-p

Comment: @AlastairG: this reminds me of a quiz I failed for lack of proper assessment of what was expected of me: **Q:** is the speed of light 300,000 km/s?  **A:** no... because I knew this was not 100% correct: the speed of light in vacuum is ~299,792.458 km/h and it varies a lot depending on the medium refractive index (barely above 200,000 km/s in typical fiber optics cables, which gives an edge to the likes of Starlink for lower latency).

Answer (score 0):

You can repeatedly use integer division and the modulo operator to extract the bits, and keep track of the groups within your loop. It sounds like a homework question, so I'm not sure how much of a service it does you to give you a full solution? Consider that you can use this algorithm to get the base-2 representation of a positive integer (in fact it works with any base >= 2):

```
int example = 40;
while (example > 0) {
    printf("%d\n", example % 2);
    example /= 2;
}
```

This will print out the bits in reverse order (that is, starting from the least significant). From here there's not much work to be done to count the groups you want to count. Should I go further or can you take it from here?

Comment: Huh? That looks like a very inefficient and complicated way to do something very simple. Easier would be `for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(int) * 8); i++) printf("%d\n", (example & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0);

Comment: @AlastairG The advantage is that it works for any base. Also, I'm guessing a good compiler would make it just as efficient as the bit-manipulation answers. Also, I'm not sure why you consider it complicated. This is how bases work.

Comment: Bases? What do you mean bases? It's just a number, a value. It has no textual representation. Bases only apply when you have a textual representation. There is no base 10 integer type or base 16 integer type, just an integer type. As such my method works just as well as yours in terms of actual output. As for a compiler making it more efficient, it's not impossible, but I doubt it. In any case it is less obvious as to what it is doing than my version, AND it changes the value passed in.

Comment: @AlastairG Regarding bases, if you replace the twos in my sample code with threes, you get a base-3 representation of `example`. Another word for "base" is "radix". More info on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_%28mathematics%29) and elsewhere. And regarding compiler optimisation, for a non-negative integer `n`: `n /= 2` is the exact same thing as `n >>= 1`, and `n % 2` is the exact same thing as `n & 1`. If you specify `unsigned int` instead of `int`, then I would certainly expect the compiler to perform these optimisations.

Comment: @AlastairG By the way, `(example & (1 << i)) ? 1 : 0` is equivalent to `(example >> i) & 1`.

Comment: @Mitch: Ah I see you were talking about the base of the OUTPUT. Now I see what you meant. Only thing is, the OP was clearly talking about binary and nothing else. As for optimisations, yes I know, but you did specify `int` in your example and not an unsigned type.

Comment: @Mitch(2): True, but the former makes it's intent more obviously clear. Yours is possibly more efficient though.

Comment: @AlastairG: Regarding "the OP was clearly talking about binary and nothing else": Arguably the OP's use of infinite leading zeroes in ....0000000000000000010 indicates a mathematical and machine-agnostic binary representation of integers, so it could make sense to approach in a general mathematical way. Not saying one way is better than the other.

Comment: Although I suppose it's likely the OP meant 0...0000000000000000010.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code
Didnt test it.. so do let me know if you find some bug

num is the input.

```
int main()
{
    int count = 0;

    int num = 0xF0000000, mask = 1; /*size of mask and num should be same. */

    int i;
    int flag= 1;


    i = sizeof(num) * 8;

    while(--i) {
         if(flag && !(num & mask)) {
            count++;
            flag = 0;
        }
        else if(num & mask)
            flag = 1;

    mask = mask<<1;
 }

 printf("\n%d\n",count);
 }

Thanks
cexpert
http://learnwithtechies.com
```

Comment: why does the editing go off.. can some help.. i am new to this site !

Comment: @cexpert Regarding formatting, see the orange/yellow question mark on the right side of the toolbar above the text area where you type in your answer. This links to an explanation of markdown. You can use four spaces at the beginning of a line to indicate a pre-formatted block of code.

Comment: Explanation for my code: I am using mask to scan each bit in the number. flag is set to 1, which means i am in '1' bit stream in the number. so if flag is 1 and num & mask is 0, then i changed from 1 to 0. So increment the count and set the flag to 0. Set flag to 1 every time you see bit 1 in the number. The code should work !

Comment: @cexpert: We don't usually post full answers to homework. Although this isn't flagged as such, the lack of practicality of such a piece of code implies it is.